# No overload for method 'Open' takes 1 or more argument

Tags: c#, mysql, excel, adox

I have a error regarding ADOX and i have no idea how to solve.

```
enter code here public static string[] GetTableExcel(string strFileName)
        {
            string[] strTables = new string[100];
            Catalog sCatalog = new Catalog();
            ADOX.Table sTable = new ADOX.Table();
            MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection sConn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection();
            sConn.Open("server=localhost; Data Source = " + strFileName + ";user id=root;Password=1;database=test;persist security info=False");
            sCatalog.ActiveConnection = sConn;
            if (sCatalog.Tables.Count > 0)
            {
                int item = 0;
                foreach (ADOX.Table tab in sCatalog.Tables)
                {
                    if (tab.Type == "TABLE")
                    {
                        strTables[item] = tab.Name;
                        item++;
                    }
                }
            }
            return strTables;
```

The error stated is that 'No overload for method 'Open' takes one argument. Any kind souls here can help me out? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection.Open(string connStr) is not available, you should call

```
MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection sConn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("server=localhost; Data Source = " + strFileName + ";user id=root;Password=1;database=test;persist security info=False");
sConn.Open();
```

Answer (score 2):

Basically in this line:

```
   sConn.Open("server=localhost; Data Source = " + strFileName + ";user id=root;Password=1;database=test;persist security info=False");
```

You are not calling the function correctly. The open function does not accept the connection string.

You should be providing the connection string when you create the MySqlConnection instance as shown below:

```
  MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection sConn = new MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection("server=localhost; Data Source = " + strFileName + ";user id=root;Password=1;database=test;persist security info=False");
```

Then you call the open function as follows:

```
  sConn.Open();
```

Hope that helps.